# Find the equation of a cylinder

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the cylinder that has directrix the curve: $x(t)=t, y(t)=t^2/2, z(t)=0$ and the generatrix is parallel to the line $${x-1\over 1}={y+2\over 1}={z\over 3}$$

I would really appreciate if you can help me how to solve this problem; are there any books of analytic geometry or links that have this kind of problems about cylinders?

Comment: By directrix you mean generator of an oblique cylinder?

Answer (score 1):

A direction vector of the straight line given is $(1,1,3)$. We are on the surface if $(x,y,z)+(u,u,3u)=(t,\frac{t^2}{2},0)$ for some $t$ and $u$.
Intuitively: sitting on the surface (at $(x,y,z)$) and stretching a vector (parallel to, say $(1,1,3)$) towards the $xy$ plane, the vector has to reach it at a point for which the directrix equation holds:

[image]

We have, therefore, the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{equation}
x+u=t\\
y+u=\frac{t^2}{2}\\
z+3u=0
\end{equation}
.$$

From the first two equations we get that

$$t^2-2t+2(x-y)=0$$

therefore
$$t_{1,2}=1\pm\sqrt{1-2(x-y)}.$$

($y\ge x-\frac{1}{2}$, since $t_{1,2}$ have to be real.) Then, because of the first equation,

$$u=1\pm \sqrt{1-2(x-y)}-x.$$

So

$$z(x,y)=-3\left(1\pm \sqrt{1-2(x-y)}-x.\right) \text{ if }\  y\ge x-\frac{1}{2}.$$
(If one checks the $\pm$ signs above, it turns out that only the negative sign works.)

I hope that this solution is OK. Unfortunately I cannot point at any general reference.